# visual studio highlighting space / horizontal line between parentheses

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would like to show a vertical line, next to the linenumbers, in my visual studio 2010 between parentheses when my courser is between those 2 parantheses.

I alread had that option enabled, but somehow its gone.

edit: is nobody using that feature? one of the very nice things when you are debugging

**Is no one using that feature??**

Edit: so last push!! there must be a way to see where the space between parentheses starts and ends.

edit: here is an image [image]

EDIT: **I still haven't found what i'm looking for**. VS is so powerful there must somewhere an option or a plugin. It is really useful when you can see where your `{` begins and ends `}`.

Anyone a clue?

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of how it looks like? No idea, to be honest.

Comment: here: http://i.imgur.com/Y8sPm.jpg  the courser is within the method

Comment: No, it is from the new dart editor. New language from google.

Comment: @Gero: I've added another little idea to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the horizontal line feature since 2008. I hated it so I haven't been looking for it either.

You should however be able to see the braces being highlighted when your cursor is on them. If not, perhaps you've changed your theme or possibly some colors in your `Options` menu.

Here's what you should try:

`Tools ->`
`Options(down at the bottom of the drop-down) ->`
 
`Environment ->`
`Fonts and Colors`

Make sure the `Show settings for:` selector is showing `Text Editor`.
The one(s) you're looking for are `Brace Matching (Highlight/Rectangle)`.

Attempt to change it to your choosing and see if the changes take place. If not, reset to the defaults and re-check it's enabled.

## Also...

Another suggestion that can be handy to get a temporary look at the extents of the body you can hover your mouse just along the margin it will highlight the most nested body. You may have to do some tweaking of your colors to make it vibrant. I use a darker color and have my code block highlighting white. I know it's not what you're looking for but it might be somewhat of a band aid.

Comment: thx, i changed the colours now to red and it highlight the matching  but i was not looking for that feature. I would like to show a horizontal line, next to the linenumbers from { to }.

Comment: ahm lol. messed vertical and horizontal up. i mean vertical line!! as shown in the picture from line 18 to line 25.

Comment: Hah, well that explains it.